# MPDF: Reset total page number

Tags: php, mpdf

I need some advice.
I create pdf with mpdf. In a same pdf i generate multiple invoices.
I need reset total page number. For exemple in a same PDF:

```
Invoice A 1 - 2  
Invoice A 2 - 2   
Invoice B 1 - 1   
Invoice C 1 - 2  
Invoice C 2 - 2   
etc...
```

At the moment i solve reset of current page number with

```
$pdf->AddPageByArray(array(resetpagenum => '1'));
```

But I don't find how to reset total page number.
When I print PDF I get

```
Invoice A 1 - 5  
Invoice A 2 - 5  
Invoice B 1 - 5  
Invoice C 1 - 5  
Invoice C 2 - 5
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Do you need to have all invoices in a single PDF? What about to generate them separately? You wouldn't need any manipulation with page numbers. If needed, you can merge them after they're generated.

Comment: On [this page](https://mpdf.github.io/headers-footers/page-numbers-date.html) it says that when you use `'{PAGENO}'` then it takes the resetting of numbering into account. The big question is, of course, what do you actually do?!

Comment: Thank for your time. I need a single PDF yes and for page number i use {PAGENO}{nb}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a different alias to print the total number of pages. Currently, you're most likely using the [alias `{nb}`](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-variables/aliasnbpg.html) which prints simply the total number of pages.

But there's also the [alias `{nbpg}`](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-variables/aliasnbpggp.html) which prints the **total number of pages considering page groups**.

It's pretty well described on the documentation page for the function [`AliasNbPageGroups()`](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/aliasnbpagegroups.html):

> `AliasNbPageGroups` – Defines the placeholder used to insert total page number of the page group or document into the document
>
> Set the value for the variable string [`aliasNbPgGp`](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-variables/aliasnbpggp.html) which is used as a placeholder used to insert total page number into the document. If you have reset the page numbering with [`AddPage()`](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/addpage.html) or [`<pagebreak>`](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/html-control-tags/pagebreak.html) the total number of pages in the current page group will be used (up to where the numbering is reset) rather the total number of pages in the whole document.

Comment: Thank a lot, it's perfect

Comment: You're welcome. BTW I just googled it for you. I have never used `mpdf` ;)